# Call backing bean method through XmlHttpRequest object

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to call a backing bean method using the javascript XmlHttpRequest object or through jQuery in JSF?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you expose the Backing Bean via HTTP (ie. using something like RESTeasy, a Servlet; etc).

But it is easier to use something like ajax4jsf. If you need to, you can use ajax4jsf's a4j:jsFunction as an intermediary between jQuery and your backing bean.